# I'm writing my first powershell script to remove old TMP/LOG files on exchange

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a custom script to keep our Exchange servers clean. It consists of several parts.

The last part is to clean TEMP folders, and it's working with no problems.

The first part is where my problem is. I want to select all .BAK .TMP and .XML files and delete them if they are over 3 days old, and select and delete all .log files if they are over 30 days old. But no files are being selected.

```
$Path ="$env:SystemDrive\Program Files (x86)\GFI\MailEssentials\EmailSecurity\DebugLogs\", "$env:SystemDrive\Program Files (x86)\GFI\MailEssentials\AntiSpam\DebugLogs\", "$env:SystemDrive\inetpub\logs", "$env:windir\System32\LogFiles"

# How long do you want to keep files by default?
$Daysback = "3"

# How long do you want to keep .log files? (Recommended 30 days at least)
$DaysbackLog = "30"


$DatetoDelete = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Daysback)
$DatetoDeleteLog = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysbackLog)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Hidden | Where-Object {($_.extension -like ".log" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDeleteLog)} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Hidden | Where-Object {($_.extension -like ".bak", "tmp", "xml" -and $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete)} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf


# The following lines clears temp folder and empty folders in the temp folder.

Get-ChildItem "$env:windir\Temp", "$env:TEMP" -recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
Get-ChildItem "$env:windir\Temp", "$env:TEMP" -recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDelete } | Where {$_.PSIsContainer -and @(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath:$_.fullname).Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
```

Comment: Im currently using this solution, but the script turns kind of ugly because i have to use a line for each file extension.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -recurse -filter "*.log" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $DatetoDeleteLog } | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue```

Comment: [1] grab all your file types at once. that will save making multiple disk reads. ///// [2] loop thru the collection. ///// [3] test for `.Extension` in either list. ///// [4] test for age. _DON'T test for a date ... use use date math and test for `.TotalDays`. why? because it is far easier to get `$DaysOld -lt $MaxDaysOld` set up correctly. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey How would he avoid making the date math calculation in the Where clause? `[DateTime]` objects are readily comparable. Calculating the date boundary as he has should yield shorter code with fewer calculations with no need to do the date math on each file object AND do the comparison to `$DaysOld`.

Comment: @Steven - i was apparently unclear. [*blush*] my intent was to say that it is FAR too easy to get date object comparisons backwards. it's a fairly common error with new-ish scripters. so ... to avoid that easy error ... i recommend comparing the `age-in-days` since that is the idea that is actually being worked on. **_it takes a few extra steps, but it VERY explicitly expresses the intent._**

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, but much of it is based on personal preference and/or performance. The latter of which is not likely to be a big design factor here.

```
$Path = @(
    "$env:SystemDrive\Program Files (x86)\GFI\MailEssentials\EmailSecurity\DebugLogs\"
    "$env:SystemDrive\Program Files (x86)\GFI\MailEssentials\AntiSpam\DebugLogs\"
    "$env:SystemDrive\inetpub\logs"
    "$env:windir\System32\LogFiles"
)

# Extensions
$Extensions = "*.bak", "*.tmp", "*.xml"

# Temp folders to clean up
$Temps = "$env:windir\Temp", "$env:TEMP"

# How long do you want to keep files by default?
$Daysback = "3"

# How long do you want to keep .log files? (Recommended 30 days at least)
$DaysbackLog = "30"

$DatetoDelete = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Daysback)
$DatetoDeleteLog = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysbackLog)

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" -Recurse -Hidden | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $DatetoDeleteLog } | 
Remove-Item -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf

# > Move filtering left, which works because you are only looking for a single
#   extension.
# > Change to -le to accommodate edge case where $_.LastWriteTime is right on 
#   the boundary.

$Extensions |
ForEach-Object{
    Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $_ -Recurse -Hidden 
} | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $DatetoDelete } | 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf

# Set up extensions as an array of wild card filters.
# -Filter is much faster than -Include which may be another alternative approach

Get-ChildItem $Temps -File -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $DatetoDelete } | 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf

Get-ChildItem $Temps -Directory -Recurse | 
Where-Object { !$_.GetFileSystemInfos() } | 
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
```

I haven't tested any of the refactor.  However, the approach is to simply rerun the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet for each needed scenario. In my experience that's faster than trying to use the `-Include` parameter to grab all the extensions in 1 shot, while still be faster and easier to read than adding to a `Where{}` clause to filter on extension.

In the part for clearing the temp folders. I use the .Net Method `.GetFileSystemInfos()` on the `[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]` objects returned from `Get-ChildItem`.  The method returns an array of all child objects, so if it's null we know the folder is empty.  That sounds complicated, but as you can see it significantly shrinks the code and will likely perform better.  I use the `-File` & `-Directory` parameters respectively to make sure to make sure I've got the right object types.

This is a little more advanced, but another way I played with to clean up the temp folders is to use a `ForEach-Object` loop with 2 process blocks.

```
$Temps | 
ForEach-Object -Process {
    # 1st process block get Empty directories:
    Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse |
    Where-Object{ !$_.GetFileSystemInfos() }
}, {
    # 2nd process block get files older than the boundary date.
    Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse |
    Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $DatetoDelete }
} |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WhatIf
```

Again untested, and I'm not sure how this will preform. Nevertheless, since I developed it thought I'd share.

Note: the `-Process` argument is necessary so that `ForEach-Object` assigns both block to process.

Check out [ForEach-Object with Multiple Script Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1#example-9--using-foreach-object-with-more-than-two-script-blocks) for more information.